# how to implement passport-local strategy when password is bad?

Tags: node.js, express, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, passport-local

I have a node, express 4, sequelize, passport, ES6 server.
I implemented the passport local strategy, it works if user found and password ok.
But when user found but wrong password it does not return the message "invalid password" but throws an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object  
POSThttp://localhost:8080/api/v2/login
```

auth.service.js

```
import passport from "passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy as JwtStrategy } from "passport-jwt";
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";

import userModel from "../modules/user/user.model";
import { db } from "../config/database.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";

const User = userModel(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize);

const localOptions = {
  usernameField: "email",
  passwordField: "password",
  session: false,
};

const jwtOptions = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
};

const localStrategy = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, async (email, password, done) => {
  try {
    // find user
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email }, raw: true });

    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: `Cannot find contact with email=${email}.` });
    }

    // check password
    const passwordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!passwordValid) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid password" });
    }

    return done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    return done(error, false);
  }
});

const jwtStrategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, (jwtPayload, done) => {
  console.log(jwtPayload);
  const user = { name: "test" };
  return done(null, false, { message: "debug" });
  // User.findOne({ id: jwt_payload.sub }, function (err, user) {
  //   if (err) {
  //     return done(err, false);
  //   }
  //   if (user) {
  //     return done(null, user);
  //   } else {
  //     return done(null, false);
  //     // or you could create a new account
  //   }
  // });
});

passport.use(localStrategy);
passport.use(jwtStrategy);

export const authLocal = passport.authenticate("local", { session: false });
export const authJwt = passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false });
```

The routes

```
import { Router } from "express";
import * as userController from "./user.controller.js";
import { authLocal } from "../../services/auth.services.js";

const routes = new Router();

routes.post("/login", authLocal, userController.login);

export default routes;
```

If I set a fake user = {name:"test"} there is no error, it looks like the done function cannot return a false or null user.